# how to show marker title in google map without touch marker in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps

I have an app that integrates Google maps (successfully) and I added a few markers (5 at most). They display just fine, each one is also given a label since they're added by "AddMarker2", but what I'd really need is that specific label to be shown (visible) at all times.

I get each of them visible by clicking on the marker bubble, but I'd need to see all those labels without clicking anything, how can this be done?

Comment: You need to make the custom image with label text and set that custom image as a marker image this is one and only way to display title labels without clicking the marker.

Comment: You can go through - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487717/add-text-on-custom-marker-on-google-map-for-ios